# Check date column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date

I have this:

```
dfData['dt']
Out[53]: 
0   2013-01-02
1   2016-10-20
Name: dt, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I try this:

```
dfData['dt'].dtype==np.datetime64
Out[56]: False
```

I also try this:

```
isinstance(dfData['dt'], pd.DatetimeIndex)
Out[62]: False
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I identify general date types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use function [`numpy.issubdtype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.issubdtype.html):

```
print (np.issubdtype(dfData['dt'].dtype, np.datetime64))
True
```

Pandas solution with [`functions for check dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/general_utility_functions.html#dtype-introspection):

```
from pandas.api.types import is_datetime64_any_dtype

print (is_datetime64_any_dtype(dfData['dt'].dtype))
True
```